# Sphinx "sphinxcontrib.httpdomain" package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I downloaded the 'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain' package and put into Sphinx-1.2 directory:

```
..../Sphinx-1.2/sphinx/sphinxcontrib/httpdomain.py
```

I modified the conf.py under the extensions

```
=[.., 'sphinx.sphinxcontrib.httpdomain']
```

and 'make clean html' failed:

> Extension error: Could not import extension
>   sphinx.sphinxcontrib.httpdomain (exception: No module named
>   sphinxcontrib.httpdomain)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `sphinx.` from the extension name. It should say `extensions = [..., 'sphinxcontrib.httpdomain']`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `sphinx.sphinxcontrib.httpdomain` module inside the Python dependencies. It could be included inside Python or just using the Sphinx builder (modifying the `config.py`as pointed on the comment, not tested by me).

To solve it 'as it is':

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-sphinxcontrib-httpdomain
```

From a Debian scratch image, I needed the following packages to successfully compile `latexpdf`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-sphinx python-sphinxcontrib-httpdomain texlive texlive-latex-extra
```

So I guess that `python-sphinxcontrib-httpdomain` also solves the problem for `make html`. Hope it helps!